# How to assign values of one class properties to another almost identical class in C#

Tags: c#, class

I have two classes `UserClient` and `UserServer` with a lot of properties

```
public class UserClient {

    public Int Id { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Email{ get; set; }
}

public class UserServer {

    public Int Id { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
}

UserClient UClient = new UserClient();//with data

UserServer UServer = new UserServer();
```

how can I assign all UClient Properties values in a smart way to UServer **at once** by ignoring Email property, not individually making each property equal to another

I want something like this UServer = UClient;

Comment: What about AutoMapper ?

Comment: Any code exmple instead of NuGet package?

Comment: Do you mean you want examples of how to use AutoMapper (in which case have you looked at the many tutorials on the web already) or that you can't use AutoMapper or indeed any extra NuGet packages (in which case that should be in the question IMO)?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I would like to use a regular C# .net framework code

Comment: If you don't want to use a package or a library, somewhere you will have to have some code that copies each property - either explicitly or by using reflection. That code would only need to be in one place though. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Right, if you don't want to use anything outside the core framework, that requirement should *definitely* be in the question. But at this point it's basically "How do I rewrite AutoMapper myself?" (assuming that you want to do this automatically via reflection rather than by hand-writing the conversion code) which begs the question of *why* you believe that would be a better course of action than using a mature, tried-and-tested package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a code example.

First you need to create mapping like

```
public class UserClientToUserServer : Profile
{
    public UserClientToUserServer()
    {
        CreateMap<UserClient, UserServer>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Then you would just initialize and simply map properties

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<UserClientToUserServer>());
var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

var uServer = mapper.Map<UserServer>(UClient);
```

This is how I would write it with Automapper if you don't want to use an extension method.

Comment: You don't actually need to create a mapper profile: You can just create the mapper config like so: `var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UserClient, UserServer>());` - the default is to ignore missing members. (It's probably good practice to create a profile though)

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are right, but still there are cases when you sometimes  need to define mapper profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using auto mapper
and here is a minimal code example of what you can do

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UserClient, UserServer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Username, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Username))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.Ignore());
});
```

Then, you can create an AutoMapper instance using the configuration and use it to map a `UserClient` instance to a `UserServer` instance

```
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
UserClient UClient = new UserClient { Id = 1, Username = "user1", Email = "user1@example.com" };
UserServer UServer = mapper.Map<UserServer>(UClient);
```

of course you would need to install `AutoMapper` package first

Answer (score 2):

> how can I assign all UClient Properties values in a smart way to
> UServer at once by ignoring Email property, not individually making
> each property equal to another

There is many more ways to do this off course and depending on your application you might find one more appropriate than the other.

Below are a few examples of the many ways to achieve this.

---

1. Method On Source Class

While this works it will introduce a direct dependency between `UserClient` and `UserServer` and add business logic to a data object that potentially requires unit tests.

```
    public class UserClient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public UserServer ToUserServer()
        {
            return new UserServer{Id = this.Id, Username = this.Username};
        }
    }
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VPqCIL)

---

2. Method On Target Class

Same as previous example, this will introduce a direct dependency between `UserServer` and `UserClient` as well as add business logic to a data object that potentially requires unit tests.

```
    public class UserServer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        
        public static UserServer FromUserClient(UserClient userClient)
        {
            return new UserServer{Id = userClient.Id, Username = userClient.Username};
        }
    }
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7xLw6m)

---

3. Using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

If you find you need to map a lot of data objects to each other in your application AutoMapper can come in very handy to centralize mapping logic away from the rest of the code.

This will lead to cleaner code as well as code which is easier to maintain and test.

While the example below uses direct initialization you can use AutoMapper with [dependency injection](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) as well.

I'm also using Profiles below but you don't have to.

Configuration Example [Using Profiles](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html):

```
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<UserProfile>());
```

Usage Example:
var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

```
    var UClient = new UserClient{Id = 1, Username = "UserClient1", Email = "UserClientEmail"};

    var UServer = mapper.Map<UserServer>(UClient);
```

AutoMapper Profile:

```
    public class UserProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<UserClient, UserServer>();
        }
    }
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XJ9uEP)

There is many ways to do this but I hope the above helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

> not individually making each property equal to another

Well somewhere, this has to happen. The fact that you don't see it doesn't mean its not there. Even using AutoMapper, you'll have to define how to map between both types at least once in some way or another.

Whats wrong with an extension method you only have to write once?

```
public static UserServer ToUserServer(this UserClient client) { ... }

uServer = uClient.ToUserServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this using reflection?

```
static void CloneProperties
        (UserClient baseClass, UserServer classTarget)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] baseClassProperties = typeof(UserClient)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Instance 
            | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        PropertyInfo[] targetClassProperties = typeof(UserServer)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Instance 
            | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo targetProperty in targetClassProperties)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo baseProperty in baseClassProperties)
            {
                if (baseProperty.Name.Equals(targetProperty.Name))
                {
                    var value = baseProperty.GetValue(baseClass);
                    targetProperty.SetValue(classTarget, value, null); 
                    break;
                }  
            }           
        }
    }
```